# How to Make Navigation View Background Transparent when slides Right

Tags: android

I am using Drawerlayout with navigationview.
When navigationview slides there is some transparent space left.
I want to change the color of this space, or make it transparent.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the content to darken when you open the drawer?

Comment: Yes i want it for some other color or transparent

Comment: `DrawerLayout#setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`, or whatever color you want.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `setScrimColor(int color)` to your `DrawerLayout` :

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.WHITE);
// OR
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setScrimColor%28int%29)